# cannot connect to MYSQL server through phpmyadmin

Tags: server, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

[image]

This is my phpmyadmin login page. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 . I am using the XAMPP server. Apache and php server are working fine  ,but I cannot access the phpmyadmin. When I use sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart . It shows mysql server is not running and it restarts it again .

Comment: Screenshot is too small

Comment: Add image to post using 'Add image ' while posting questions. Do not give links.

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL from the command line?

Comment: No I cannot connect neither using command line.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lampp folder from the /opt folder using the command

> sudo rm -rf  /opt/lampp

and now make a clean install again. But still I cannot figure out what my problem was.